# Ubuntu 19.10 desktop icons

Tags: desktop-icons

I add in tweaks home folder and trash but they do not appear on the desktop...

[image]

Comment: Did you log your user out and back in again? Some settings require that for a change to take effect.

Comment: Yes i did but it did not help...